# How to order the rows in Laravel based on a column's value?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table of products with city, state and country name.

If a user visits my shop, the products from his city should be displayed first, **then** the products from his state and **finally** the products from his country.

For a table,

```
+----+---------+-------------+------------+---------------+|

| id | product |    city     |   state    |    country    |

+----+---------+-------------+------------+---------------+

|  1 | guava   | Julian      | California | United States |

|  2 | apple   | London      | NA         | England       |

|  3 | orange  | Los Angeles | California | United States |

|  4 | grapes  | Zion        | Illinois   | United States |

|  5 | banana  | Canyon      | California | United States |

+----+---------+-------------+------------+---------------+
```

**if a user from Los Angeles visits my shop, the expected results should be of order `3,1,5,3,2`.**

I read the laravel docs and also tried searching in stack overflow but couldn't find any apt answers.

My code for now is

```
 Products::where('city",$usercity)->orWhere('state',$userstate)
 ->orWhere('country',$usercountry)->get();
```

I don't have an idea on what to use for the `orderBy` part!

Comment: I understand your question, you want to sort by country. User country first then other country. Provide your query code, so could help

Comment: Do you have any way of determining where a user is from?

Comment: What you want is easy enough but the first question I would have is how do you know what state the user is in?  Ideally, the user table should have a relation to state and country which can then be used to simply sort by the matching state and so on, but without understanding the code you have and the existing relationships there is nowhere to start.

Comment: Yeah, I know where the user is from using the ip address or the city set by the user.

Comment: My code for now is Products::where('city",$usercity)->orWhere('state',$userstate)->orWhere('country',$usercountry)->get();

I don't have an idea on what to use for the orderBy part!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

### [`Case`](https://www.sqlshack.com/case-statement-in-sql/)

which returns a value on a **specified** condition, In your case (no pun intended) it returns the order of products.

---

We will use `orderByRaw()` to integrate the `case` statement.

### But

you need to be careful because this will cause [`SQL injection`](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) And we don't want that so we use **bindings**:

```
Products::where('city',$usercity)
->orWhere('state',$userstate)
->orWhere('country',$usercountry)
->orderByRaw('
         CASE
            WHEN city = ? THEN 1 
            WHEN state = ? THEN 2
            WHEN country = ? THEN 3
            ELSE 4
        END',[$usercity,$userstate,$usercountry])->get();
```

And that will got you the desired result hopefully.

*P.S: Follow Laravel naming conventions which says: Model's names should be singular not plural (**`Product`** not **`Products`**)*.

Comment: This is exactly I was searching for! Thank you so much <3 :)